# Visa/ESTA requirements for spouse

Tags: visas, usa

I have an Italian passport and I want to go to the USA with my husband, but he holds an African passport. What are the requirements? We actually live in the UK and he holds a biometric permit.

Comment: What passport exactly does your husband have?

Comment: @lambshaanxy it doesn't matter.  There is no African country in the US visa waiver program.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you want to visit for tourism, to see friends or family, or for similar personal reasons, your husband will need a B-2 visa (or a combination B-1/B-2 visa).  Because you are an Italian citizen, you can use the visa waiver program if you meet the other criteria (including that your visit is not longer than 90 days), are not disqualified (for example because of travel to Iran, Iraq, Libya, North Korea, Somalia, Sudan, Syria or Yemen on or after March 1, 2011 or to Cuba on or after January 12, 2021), and have an approved ESTA.  Your being eligible for ESTA doesn't affect your husband's needing a visa, nor does his UK residence permit.

If the purpose of your visit is something other than "business or pleasure" then both you and your husband will need a visa, of some type other than B-1 or B-2.